# Git rebase from from one particular commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, version-control, rebase

Assume my git branches looks like this

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- F -- * -- G -- H -- * -- K ( Main branch )
      \
       G -- H -- I -- J ( Feature branch )
```

one guy created a new Feature branch and coded something in that , later he copy pasted that every single commit of feature branch into main branch ( G -- H ) . still he coded on that branch, Now i was instructed to code in that branch , Now i have to rebase Feature branch into Main branch from ( Commit I ), How can i ??

Now I have to rebase those commits into main from one particular commit, Looking for a solution to overcome this issue .
Mostly i use Intellij for git.

Comment: From a terminal: run `git rebase -i main`. An editor will open with the commits to replay, if G or H are present, just delete them from that file, then save & exit. The result will be I and J on top of K.

Comment: branches are cheap.  When someone tells you to "code in that branch", don't.  Make your own branch, code there, and then update the remote as needed.  The sooner you understand that , the sooner you will grok git.